# Spread dataframe issue in Python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to reformat / spread my dataframe from key, value columns to wide format:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
'a':['aa','bb', 'a', 'k', 'aa','bb', 'a', 'k'],
'value': ['zzuz', 44, 'DE', 55, 'zdfdz', 454, 'SE', 155]})
test.pivot(columns='a', values='value',index='id')
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
aa     bb  a  k
zzuz   44  DE 55
zdfdz  454 SE 155
```

I am trying to do this with .pivot without luck, please guide me what I am missing here?

```
test.pivot(columns='a', values='value')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `groupby()`+`cumcount()` to tracking position and that will act as index of `pivot()` and `rename_axis()` to renaming axis(a bit of cleanup/if needed):

```
test['key']=test.groupby('a').cumcount()
out=test.pivot(columns='a', values='value',index='key')
out=out.rename_axis(columns=None,index=None)
```

OR(in 1 step)

```
out=(test.assign(key=test.groupby('a').cumcount())
         .pivot(columns='a', values='value',index='key')
         .rename_axis(columns=None,index=None))
```

output of `out`:

```
     a  aa      bb      k
0   DE  zzuz    44      55
1   SE  zdfdz   454     155
```

Comment: @SteveS you want to pivot your dataframe on the basis of 'a' column so we are assigning a number to 'a' column so that it can be pivoted accordingly....but if you use 'id' then your dataframe is pivoted but not according to what you want